# Is there a penalty for not filing my new passport with NEXUS immediately?

Tags: legal, canadian-citizens, passport-renewals, nexus, trusted-traveler

I just got my new Canadian passport after becoming a Canadian citizen in April. I am going to out of country for two months and my understanding is this change will require a new NEXUS card to be sent -- but I won't be here to pick it up. Is it OK with the NEXUS program (which is rather strict) if I wait until I am back and handle it when I land? Or am I already in trouble for not showing up at the Enrollment Centre with the citizenship certificate ASAP?

As I am not entering the United States on this trip (I will move within Schengen and the CTA) I do not need my NEXUS card this time.

Comment: Congrats on the citizenship :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I visited the NEXUS office at the YVR airport and was told:

1. There is no penalty
2. Do not use your card for now but it indeed didn't expire.
3. Your passport is not enough, you need your citizenship certificate as well. (Doh!)
4. You do not need to schedule an appointment for this just go to the enrollment centre.

Comment: Why would you need your citizenship certificate?  Do they imagine that the Canadian government would issue you a passport without first checking whether your naturalization was legitimate?

Comment: I was repeatedly told my passport is not enough...

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations on becoming a Canadian citizen. While you won't be travelling through the U.S., you will be leaving and entering Canada, and depending on which Canadian airports are on your itinerary, your NEXUS privileges will save you time and grief (especially if they involve busy airport hubs). Why don't you call (or drop in to) your nearest NEXUS Enrolment Centre to find out how your specific circumstances can be accommodated? If you don't reach an officer by telephone, your call will be returned within 24 hours. While there's no penalty for not immediately filing your new citizenship information with NEXUS, you may be able to travel on your current NEXUS card (even though it displays your other citizenship) and your new Canadian passport. Depending on the time of your departure, if you arrive early enough at the NEXUS Enrolment Centre (you don't need an appointment), your information could be changed in time for you to use the NEXUS screening lanes, and the self-serve kiosks on your return. A conversation in advance will confirm exactly what documentation will be needed. Good luck and enjoy your trip. Here's a link to NEXUS concerning changes to citizenship information: http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/contact-coordonnees-eng.html and contact numbers and hours of operation for NEXUS Enrolment Centres: http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/location-eng.html

Comment: I think this answer is suggesting that the OP can file the new passport from anywhere in the world, in a few minutes of typing, and therefore does not need to risk any penalties.